# How to change RegEx so it works in SQL Server?

Tags: regex, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xsd, xsd-validation

I have following regex:

```
/^((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\|?))*$/g
```

I need it to validate input (of list of IP addresses (IP v.4) delimited by pipe) using `XSD`, like:

```
192.168.10.11|192.168.10.10
```

I generate `XSD` using `T-SQL`. When I use this RegEx I got following error:

> Error Message: Invalid regular expression
>   "/^((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\|?))*$/g"
>   near the offset 5.

Any idea how to rewrite it or where to look to fix it?

Remark: the following RegEx is generated but not validated the input:

```
/^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(\|?))*$/g
```

T-SQL for generate:

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION schFile0000001234 AS 
'<xsd:schema
targetNamespace="http://example.com/brg/"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://example.com/brg/"
xmlns:mstns="http:/example.com/brg/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
version="1.0.1"
>
  <xsd:complexType name="ct0000006847_KDK_XXX_Front_Parameters">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="KDK_XXX_Front_AllowedSourceIPs" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="1000"/>
            <xsd:pattern value="/^((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\|?))*$/g"/>
          </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>';
GO
```

**EDIT:** in general I try to check for white space (I need to be "No white space"). I try to make good check to be sure that also the IPs in the list are valid. Obviously it is too complex to be created from T-SQL. So may be only to check for white space?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012 doesn't have something like Oracle's REGEXP_LIKE. And LIKE or PATINDEX are much more limited to look for patterns.  Using the LIKE syntax will be a challenge for this one ;)

Comment: Are you asking how to fix your current T-SQL code to generate the proper regex for the XSD?  I think you should add the T-SQL code to your question in that case.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the string start `/^` and string end `*$` tags, as well as the `/g` option. In other words, try the following pattern:

```
<xs:pattern value="(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\|?))*"/>
```

However, the above regex accepts an extra trailing `|`. To avoid that, you can use the following pattern:

```
<xs:pattern value="((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\|((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))*"/>
```

I recommend using `[0-9]` instead of `\d`, to avoid matching digits in other languages, such as `৩` (but you already edited your question to avoid this).

Answer (score 1):

One approach with pure T-SQL (but not within XSD) might be to split your input and validate it *old school*:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourIPList VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('192.168.10.11|192.168.10.10');

WITH SplittedAtPipe AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS IP_index 
          ,YourIPList
          ,[ip].value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') AS OneIp
    FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(YourIPList,'|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS IPXml) A
    CROSS APPLY A.IPXml.nodes('/x') B([ip])
) 
,SplittedAtDot AS
(
    SELECT SplittedAtPipe.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Frg_index 
          ,frg.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') AS IPFragment
    FROM SplittedAtPipe
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(OneIp,'.','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS IPFragment) A
    CROSS APPLY A.IPFragment.nodes('/x') B(frg)
)
SELECT * 
FROM SplittedAtDot;
```

You can check each fragment if it is numeric (`TRY_CAST`), if the `INT` is between 0 and 255, if there are blanks (`DATALENGTH` vs. `LEN`) and so on...

Hope this helps

Comment: In general, yes, @Shnugo. But this step is before T-SQL. Our engine prepares the input which is tested via XSD and then is processed. In this case business logic requires (in our case) to implement this in XSD Schema.